# intent filter is not working as my expactation

Tags: android, android-intent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.desk.rnd">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".ShowActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

above xml is my full Manifest.xml code.

I'm using Samsung S4, Note8, Momo Emulator as test phone.

I couldn't get url when share web page in some browser.

Test Browser : Yandex, Samsung default, Chrome.

If action is SEND and remove BROWABLE in category, I can show my app in share window.

But this is not what I want.

How can I get Url from link sharing?

[Solution]

```
<activity android:name=".ShowActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: @StefanoMtangoo of caurse. I trying to extract text from webview with sharing url from browser.

Comment: which app is the source of that data? Can you check if this link helps? It outlines something that I believe you are trying to do
https://www.androidcode.ninja/android-share-intent-example/

Comment: @StefanoMtangoo thank you for your comment. I found ridiculous solution. action is SEND, category is DEFAULT, data's mimeType is 'text/plain'. there is no BROWSABLE category, no VIEW action.  but this is work fine.

Comment: Please post your answer with working version of question code to help future searchers. Hongera for solving it!